# Where is a good place to tuck CreatedDate and ModifiedDate in a DataRow?

Tags: c#, .net, datarow

I have the following code

```
public class SpecialItemRow : DataRow
    {
        public SpecialItemRow(DataRowBuilder builder)
            : base(builder)
        {
            CreatedDate = DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString();
        }

        public string ItemName { get { return Convert.ToString(base["_ItemName"]); } set { base["_ItemName"] = value; _UpdateModifiedDate(); } }
        public string Price { get { return Convert.ToString(base["_Price"]); } set { base["_Price"] = value; _UpdateModifiedDate(); } }
        public string CreatedDate { get { return Convert.ToString(base["_CreatedDate"]); } set { base["_CreatedDate"] = value; _UpdateModifiedDate(); } }
        public string ModifiedDate { get { return Convert.ToString(base["_ModifiedDate"]); } set { base["_ModifiedDate"] = value; } }

        private void _UpdateModifiedDate()
        {
            ModifiedDate = DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString();
        }
    }
```

which tries to set the modified and created dates automatically. but it turns out that those are not the right places to put. is there any other overridable methods to set these values? Thanks.

Comment: How do you actually create instances of this type since you can't really get instances of DataRowBuilder - not having a public constructor - ? (or maybe I'm missing something).

Comment: @tzup this constructor gets called when you have a corresponding typed DataTable whose NewRowFromBuilder() is overriden to create this typed DataRow.

Answer (score 0):

Do this in `DataTable` using [OnRowChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.onrowchanged.aspx) (or OnRowChanging). For example,

```
public class SpecialItemTable : DataTable
{

   protected override void OnRowChanged(DataRowChangeEventArgs e)
   {
      if (e.Action == DataRowAction.Add)
      {
         r.Row["CreatedDate"] = DateTime.Now;
      }
      else if (e.Action == DataRowAction.Change)
      {
         var time = DateTime.Now;
         // Check to prevent the cascaded row change events
         if ((time - (DateTime)e.Row["LastUpdated"]).TotalMilliseconds > 2)
         {
            e.Row["LastUpdated"] = time;
         }
      }
   }
}
```

*(Disclaimer: Untested code - provided to just give an idea)*